# Is there a way to use signalr as a pure websocket server [ws://]?

Tags: c#, websocket, server, signalr

So there are some libraries on github that try to implement the web-socket protocol using C#.
But then we have the mature **signalr** built by Microsoft and support Web socket protocol.
Is there a way to configure signalr as a **pure web-socket server**, so that a client can directly connect using ws://localhost/chat for example.

thank you.

Comment: There is a tutorial available which describes signalr self hosting: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use websockets directly with SignalR at the moment. SignalR uses [a protocol](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) that needs to be followed or you won't be able to connect to the server at all.

**EDIT**

SignalR for Asp.NET Core allows connecting to the server using bare websockets. This [post](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-23-asp-net-sockets/) shows how to do this.

Comment: Any future plans ?

Comment: Yes. Some details here: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/196

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer - see my tweet from yesterday: https://twitter.com/moozzyk/status/795142711653171200

Comment: I'm not following ... is that a proof that Websocket worked with Signalr ?

Comment: This is with the new version of SignalR where you should be able to connect to the server with just bare websockets.

Comment: @Pawel: do you have an example of using websockets to connect to SignalR Core?

Comment: There is a social weather sample that uses just webSockets: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/samples/SocialWeather/wwwroot/index.html#L70-L100. It is actually more than that - you can read the entire story here: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-23-asp-net-sockets/

Comment: @Pawel, but this means on server side we are supposed to use  ConnectionHandlers, right? using Hub is not an option for this scenario, or?

Comment: It depends. My understanding is that the clients allow skipping negotiate when you use webSocket transport. This means that if you wanted to connect to a hub with bare websocket you could only then you need to conform to SignalR protocol when sending/receiving data. If you want to use your own format I don't think you can use hubs on the server side.